# split google sheet by column into multiple files on docs, but i cant make it download the files link as .xlsx correctly

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

i have a code that splits a google sheet into multiple new files by a column criteria, my ideia was also to download it into excel files using the link methood;
`'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+sheetId+'/export?format=xlsx'`
But when i excecute a foreach loop to click the generated links after the sheets are split into the drive it only downloads empty sheets, but my sheets inside driver have the correct data as it should and i cant figure out why the download part doesnt work when i split the sheets docs in more than 2 archives...

Example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lN79lht6Ljh7pwBQ1FoGJtSwSZf9WDTza2r4Y_psghY/edit?usp=sharing

my code so far

```
const activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const spreadSheet = activeSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
const sRange = spreadSheet.getDataRange();
const rawData = sRange.getValues();
const activeRange = spreadSheet.getActiveRange();
const newSheetName = activeRange.getValues();
const rangeCol = activeRange.getColumn();

let outputArray = [];// array that'll contain the sheets names

//creates a array with values names from the selected range
function removeusingSet (arr) {
  let outputArray = Array.from(new Set(arr))
  return outputArray
}
// gets the names on the column that'll be used as split criteria
let namesLower = removeusingSet(newSheetName.flat());

//converts the names to uppercase
names = namesLower.map(function (x) {
  return x.toUpperCase();
});

function splitSheet () {
  let sheetLink = [];

  for (let x = 1; x < names.length; x++) {
    if (names[x] !== '' && names[x] !== null) {
      //creates a new archive with the split col name
      let newSS = SpreadsheetApp.create(names[x]);
      let newId = newSS.getId();
      let newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(newId);
      let newSheetName = newSheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
      newSheetName.setName(names[x]); // renames the default sheet created with the col name

      let target = newSheet.getSheetByName(names[x]); // gets the newly created sheet reference
      let data = []; // empty array

      data.push(rawData[0]); // gets the first row and set it as a header
      
      // filters the data by checking if the select column matches the current name in the loop
      for (let y = 0; y < rawData.length; y++) {
        if(rawData[y][rangeCol-1].toUpperCase() === names[x]) {
          data.push(rawData[y]);
        }
      }
      // clears any data in the select sheet and sets the newly filtered data 
      target.clear({contentsOnly: true});
      target.getRange(target.getLastRow()+1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
      sheetLink.push('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+newId+'/export?format=xlsx'); // stores the sheet link inside the sheetLink array
    }
  }

  // piece that should download the sheets generated by the for loop before but only downloads empty files
  sheetLink.forEach((openUrl) => {
    let html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<html><script>'
      +'window.close = function(){window.setTimeout(function(){google.script.host.close()},9)};'
      +'var a = document.createElement("a"); a.href="'+openUrl+'"; a.target="_blank";'
      +'if(document.createEvent){'
      +'  var event=document.createEvent("MouseEvents");'
      +'  if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("firefox")>-1){window.document.body.append(a)}'                          
      +'  event.initEvent("click",true,true); a.dispatchEvent(event);'
      +'}else{ a.click() }'
      +'close();'
      +'</script>'
      // Offer openUrl as clickable link in case above code fails.
      +'<body style="word-break:break-word;font-family:sans-serif;">Failed to open automatically. <a href="'+openUrl+'" target="_blank" onclick="window.close()">Click here to proceed</a>.</body>'
      +'<script>google.script.host.setHeight(40);google.script.host.setWidth(410)</script>'
      +'</html>'
    );
  Utilities.sleep(1000);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog( html, "Opening ..." );
  });
}
```

Comment: I have tried using your code and it was downloading the last file as .xlsx and it is not empty. If possible can you share a dummy/copy of your spreadsheet so we can replicate what you have.

Comment: @Logan i forgot to mention that it works when i split sheets in 2 with not many lines, but if i try to split in 4 or more it just download dummy files or sometimes it only downloads only one file even if the console logs the links i created correcty.
Heres an example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lN79lht6Ljh7pwBQ1FoGJtSwSZf9WDTza2r4Y_psghY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: May I also ask how you are selecting the input? Do you just highlight the range then run the script?

Comment: i highlight the column i want and then run the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Suggestion:

Upon testing your code it is not being able to export the sheets directly as xlsx file, it is resulting to only the last file having data. Here's an approach you can try. Try converting the spreadsheets file first in your google drive before initiating the download:

##### Code.gs

```
const activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const spreadSheet = activeSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
const sRange = spreadSheet.getDataRange();
const rawData = sRange.getValues();
const activeRange = spreadSheet.getActiveRange();
const newSheetName = activeRange.getValues();
const rangeCol = activeRange.getColumn();

let outputArray = [];// array that'll contain the sheets names

//creates a array with values names from the selected range
function removeusingSet (arr) {
  let outputArray = Array.from(new Set(arr))
  return outputArray
}
// gets the names on the column that'll be used as split criteria
let namesLower = removeusingSet(newSheetName.flat());

//converts the names to uppercase
names = namesLower.map(function (x) {
  return x.toUpperCase();
});

function splitSheet () {
  let sheetLink = [];

  for (let x = 1; x < names.length; x++) {
    if (names[x] !== '' && names[x] !== null) {
      //creates a new archive with the split col name
      let newSS = SpreadsheetApp.create(names[x]);
      let newId = newSS.getId();
      let newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(newId);
         
      let newSheetName = newSheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
      newSheetName.setName(names[x]); // renames the default sheet created with the col name

      let target = newSheet.getSheetByName(names[x]); // gets the newly created sheet reference
      let data = []; // empty array

      data.push(rawData[0]); // gets the first row and set it as a header
      
      // filters the data by checking if the select column matches the current name in the loop
      for (let y = 0; y < rawData.length; y++) {
        if(rawData[y][rangeCol-1].toUpperCase() === names[x]) {
          data.push(rawData[y]);
        }
      }
      // clears any data in the select sheet and sets the newly filtered data 
      target.clear({contentsOnly: true});
      target.getRange(target.getLastRow()+1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
      sheetLink.push(newId); // stores the sheet link inside the sheetLink array

      var file = DriveApp.getFileById(newId);
      let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1Wh1dWIXeZV0ERe7kAdW_BEuuq8RSQvLd");
      file.moveTo(folder)
    }
  }
}

function getIdsInFolder(folderID){
  var fileIDs = []
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var contents = folder.getFiles();
  var cnt = 0;
  var file;

  while (contents.hasNext()) {
        var file = contents.next();
        cnt++;
           fileIDs.push(file.getId())

  };
  return fileIDs;
}

function convertToXLSX() {
  var sheetIds = getIdsInFolder("1Wh1dWIXeZV0ERe7kAdW_BEuuq8RSQvLd") //change the folder ID below to reflect your source sheet folder's ID 
  for (var i=0; i < sheetIds.length; i++){
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetIds[i]);
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=" + sheetIds[i] + "&exportFormat=xlsx";

    var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
      }
    });

    var fileBlob = response.getBlob();
    var xlsxFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("13aMw1R_yZg-gzIvROQPrh5Xcp2OZ96m3"); // Replace with the ID of the folder where you want to save the XLSX file
    xlsxFolder.createFile(fileBlob.setName(spreadsheet.getName() + ".xlsx"));
  };
}

function downloadFiles(){
    var xlsxIds = getIdsInFolder("13aMw1R_yZg-gzIvROQPrh5Xcp2OZ96m3"); //change the folder ID below to reflect your source XLSX folder's ID 
    xlsxIds.forEach((openUrl) => {
    let html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<html><script>'
      +'window.close = function(){window.setTimeout(function(){google.script.host.close()},9)};'
      +'var a = document.createElement("a"); a.href="'+'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+openUrl+'/export?'+'"; a.target="_blank";'
      +'if(document.createEvent){'
      +'  var event=document.createEvent("MouseEvents");'
      +'  if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("firefox")>-1){window.document.body.append(a)}'                          
      +'  event.initEvent("click",true,true); a.dispatchEvent(event);'
      +'}else{ a.click() }'
      +'close();'
      +'</script>'
      // Offer openUrl as clickable link in case above code fails.
      +'<body style="word-break:break-word;font-family:sans-serif;">Failed to open automatically. <a href="'+'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+openUrl+'/export?'+'" target="_blank" onclick="window.close()">Click here to proceed</a>.</body>'
      +'<script>google.script.host.setHeight(40);google.script.host.setWidth(410)</script>'
      +'</html>'
    );
  Utilities.sleep(5000);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog( html, "Opening ..." );
  });
}
```

##### ui.gs

```
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const menu = ui.createMenu('Split Sheet');
  menu.addItem('Split Sheet', 'splitSheet')
  menu.addItem('Convert to XLSX', 'convertToXLSX')
  menu.addItem('Download files in XLSX Folder', 'downloadFiles')
  menu.addToUi();
}
```

I have separated your function into 3. The first function which is where you split the highlighted rows into multiple spreadsheet files and put it all in a folder. The second function is where it will convert all the spreadsheets in that folder to xlsx and save it in another folder. The third it will download all the xlsx files to your local.